# When I use Java to write sparkSQL, I get what the number of fields does not line up

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

the code is following:

```
    org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset<Row> df= sasSession.createDataFrame(rowRDD,Record.class);

    Encoder<Record> rowEncoder= org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.kryo(Record.class);

    Dataset<Record> ds1=new org.apache.spark.sql.sas.Dataset(SASession,df.logicalPlan(),rowEncoder);
```

SASEssion extends SparkSession.

The Exception is :
Try to map struct<> to Tuple1, but failed as the number of fields does not line up.

The Record Class is :

```
public class Record {
    private Long event_time_st;
    private Long event_time_ed;
    public Record(Long st,Long ed){
        this.event_time_st=st;
        this.event_time_ed=ed;
}
```

}
The RDD is this:

```
JavaRDD<Record> rowRDD=sasSession.sparkContext()
    .textFile("/Users/file.txt",1).toJavaRDD().map(
         s->{
             String[] parts = s.split(",");
             Record record = new Record(Long.getLong(parts[1].trim()), Long.getLong(parts[2].trim()));
             return record;
            }
    );
```

Comment: It would be great if you showed your RDD content and the Record class

Comment: The Record class is simple:
public class Record {
    private Long event_time_st;    private Long event_time_ed;
    public Record(Long st,Long ed){
        this.event_time_st=st;
        this.event_time_ed=ed;
    }
}

Comment: The Format is not good , forgiving me ..

Comment: Now, it's ok...